# TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined (React Fetching From Database)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have issues with this function that it worked well with dummydatabase.js file that I created but when I fetched from the database, it just stopped working...

[image]

I thought it was not fetching properly, but it's working fine. I don't understand why it's not working...

Please help and thank you in advance!

Edit:
This is the Error that I get. I'm sorry if my question was not clear! ^^;

[image]

Edit2: Here's the code for the entire page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox';
//import Group from '../components/Group';
import GroupList from '../components/Group/GroupList';
//import './App.css';
import { exportedgroups } from '../dummyGroups';

function GroupBox() {


    const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
    const [searchfield, setSearchfield] = useState('');



    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/groups/get_all_groups')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(groups => { setGroups(groups.data.groups);
                console.log('GroupBox');
                console.log(groups.data.groups)
                console.log('exportedgroups');
                console.log(exportedgroups);
            });

        // setGroups(exportedgroups);
        // console.log("local data" + exportedgroups);

        // const getAllGroups = async () => {
        //     let groupData = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/groups/get_all_groups');
        //     let groupList = await groupData.json();
        //     setGroups(groupList.data.groups);
        // }

        // getAllGroups();
    }, []);

    console.log(groups);
    const onSearchChange = (event) => {
        setSearchfield(event.target.value);
    }
    const filteredGroups = groups.filter(group => {
        console.log("FilteredGroup");
        console.log(group);
        return group.name.includes(searchfield);
    });

    return (
        <div className='GroupBox'>
            <div className='flex'>
                <div className='flex flex-column'>
                    <div className='flex justify-start fw1 f3'>
                        Groups
                        </div>
                    <div className='flex justify-start'>
                        <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className='GroupList'>
                        <GroupList groups={filteredGroups} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

}

export default GroupBox;
```

Comment: You should tell us what's your actual issue. Like posting a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: @ʎzɐɹƆ Thank you! I have included the screenshot of what I'm getting!

Comment: What's the initial value of state?

Comment: @ʎzɐɹƆ No, you shouldn't post screenshots of code or error messages. Paste it in as text using code blocks  instead. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon why do you tag me tho? :D

Comment: @ʎzɐɹƆ Sorry I included the code as well

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Sorry I included the code as well

Comment: You should use conditional rendering to output your GroupList component.
`groups.length>0 ? <GroupList groups={filteredGroups} /> : "Empty"`
Something like the above so that you only use properties inside your groups when individual elements exist. What's happening now is that the component renders before state is updated and function is invoked when the state is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your name field value getting as undefined.

try this one,

```
const filteredGroups = groups.filter(group => {
    console.log("FilteredGroup");
    console.log(group);
    return group.name?.includes(searchfield); //adding "?" mark 
});
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I don't know why putting the question mark works... Would you mind explaining it to me or guide me to a page that explains? Thank you again!

Comment: In this case group.name value can be undefined, null, or an empty string. then you can use the "?" mark and it checks group.name has a value or not. if it has a value .includes will check and otherwise return false.